# c++ library for copying array contents to the pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int a[4]={1,2,3,4};
int* b = new int[4];
```

Is there any library function like std::copy to copy the elements from an array a at to pointer b in c++ ?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::copy(a, a + 4, b);`?

Comment: yes its works with std::copy(a, a + 4, checked_array_iterator<int *>(b, 4)); thanks.

Comment: with std::copy(a, a + 4,b); in vc++ latest it is giving errors.

Comment: then there is something wrong with vc++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called `std::vector<>`; you would use it in your code as follows:

```
std::vector<int> a { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto b = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any library function like std::copy to copy the elements from an array a at to pointer b in c++ ?

Yes, that's `std::copy`:

```
 std::copy( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), b );
```